# Multiple entries into a SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When I enter a string into my DB, I am able to retrieve it. But if I open the db and place another string into the DB again and close it, the entries don't exist...

```
            entry.open();
            entry.putChampion1IntoDb(jsonString);
            entry.close();



            entry.open();
            entry.putChampion2IntoDb(jsonString2);
            entry.close();

    public long putChampion1IntoDb(String json) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_CHAMPION_1, json);

        return mDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public long putChampion2IntoDb(String json) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_CHAMPION_2, json);

        return mDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Then when I call my DB class to retrieve the data, the string comes back null

```
public JSONObject getChampions2() throws JSONException {
        Cursor c = mDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, mColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String jsonFeed = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHAMPION_2));
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonFeed);
        return json;
}
```

Maybe I'm navigating through the DB wrong with the c.moveToFirst();

I would have about 5 columns and just 1 row. (At least in my head I picture it like this)

---

|Champion1|Champion2|Champion3|Champion4|Champion5|

The first time I .open() and .putChampionIntoDB(string), The key associated is the first column.
The cursor is associated with the rows correct? So, c.moveToFirst() moves to the first row where all my information is stored, correct?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't understand how database works. Every time when you are calling insert, you are inserting new row. Really you have such data:
|Champion1|Champion2|Champion3|Champion4|Champion5|

|somedata |null     |null     |null     |null     |

|null     |somedata |null     |null     |null     |

and so on. That's why, when you retrieve first row and try to get KYY_CHAMPION2 it's null.

I think, you really need to make table

|_id|champion|

and store each portion of data in separate row. Then you can easily iterate throw them.

If you still want to store data in one row, you need to call db.update() after first time instead of db.insert(). But when you call update you must identify which row you want to update. If you don't have some column as primary key it can be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense.
so,
|_id|champion_key_1|      |_id|champion_key_2|
.... so on...

well its hard to put rows in this comment